# Is there a way to restrict KitchenPC's recipe modeler by submitted ingredients?

Tags: c#, kitchenpc

Right now, when using the console, the response we’re getting on input doesn’t seem to be restrictive to the ingredients submitted.  I'm receiving recipes back that *include* those ingredients, but also many more.

granulated sugar, eggs

> > "Title: Caramelized Walnuts --- Description: ... --- Cook Time:..." 
> >     "Title: Dad's Beer Bread --- Description: ... --- Cook Time:..." 
> >     "Title: Best Brownies --- Description: ... --- Cook Time:..." 
> >     "Title: Plum Jam --- Description: ... --- Cook Time:..." 
> >     "Title: Buttermilk Biscuits --- Description: ... --- Cook Time:..." 
> >     ———

Is there a way to generate a response which only utilizes the submitted ingredients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *recipe modeler* (which attempts to find recipes that efficiently use ingredients and amounts you give it) will always return the specified number of recipes (for example, 5).  In other words, very rarely would it say "You asked for 5 but I could only find 2" unless there flat out wasn't enough data in the underlying data source.  So, don't really think of it as a search engine.  Think of it more as a suggestion engine.

It's finding recipes that include other ingredients because it doesn't have any other choice.  There would be few, if any, recipes that only contain *sugar* and *eggs*, but nothing else.  The modeler will consider any recipe that contains *at least* one of the ingredients in your list, and try to optimize for the fewest number of total addtional ingredients.  In other words, it wants your aggregated shopping list to be as short as possible.  If I recall correctly, it even trends towards *more common* ingredients, to increase the likelihood that the user doesn't have to make a trip to the store.

The exact algorithm the modeler uses, at this time, isn't designed to be extended.  However, if you wanted to change the design, the place to look would be in the `Fish` method of [ModelingSession.cs](https://github.com/KitchenPC/core/blob/master/src/Core/Modeler/ModelingSession.cs).  Right now, if `pantryIngredients` is not null, it picks a random item in that array and finds a random recipe that uses it.  There isn't really an index available in memory to find recipes that contain *all* the pantry items, so you'd need to build this index before `Generate` was called.  This is not a trivial amount of work, and unless your user interface allows the user to specify a large number of available ingredients, it would probably just yield very few results each time.

**Now, what you seem to be after is more of a *search* feature.**

With that said, if you wanted to find recipes that *only* use a set of ingredients, you could create a search provider to do this.  The built in search providers (Both `StaticSearch` and `NHSearch`) treat ingredient includes as an "OR" clause.  Meaning find me recipes that contain "sugar" OR "eggs".  There is no construct for "find me recipes that contain both sugar and eggs" nor is there a construct for "find me recipes that contain sugar and eggs and no other ingredients".  However, you can easily implement this yourself.  You'd implement [ISearchProvider](https://github.com/KitchenPC/core/blob/master/src/Core/Context/ISearchProvider.cs) and pass this in when you define your context:

```
// Context connected to local database
var dbConfig = Configuration<DBContext>.Build
   .Context(DBContext.Configure
      .Adapter(DatabaseAdapter.Configure
         .DatabaseConfiguration(PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82.ConnectionString(@"<your conn str>")
         )
         .SearchProvider(new YourSearchProvider()) // <--- Pass in an instance of your search provider
      )
      .Identity(() => new AuthIdentity(new Guid("c52a2874-bf95-4b50-9d45-a85a84309e75"), "Mike"))
   ).Create();
```

`YourSearchProvider` would implement `ISearchProvider`, and the Search method would locate recipes in whatever manner you wish.  See [NHSearch.cs](https://github.com/KitchenPC/core/blob/master/src/DB/NHSearch.cs) for an example of how to implement this using a SQL data source.  One could argue the NHSearch provider should support this fluently.  I've [logged an issue](https://github.com/KitchenPC/core/issues/3) to track this suggestion.